# Sort javascript imports by file path in intellj

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I'm trying to find a plugin or builtin function which could sort imports by file path.

For example,

```
import { Formatter } from 'homeProject/B/Formatter';
import { Router } from 'homeProject/B';
import { UUID } from 'homeProject/A/zzzzz';
```

Should be

```
import { UUID } from 'homeProject/A/zzzzz';
import { Router } from 'homeProject/B';
import { Formatter } from 'homeProject/B/Formatter';
```

Because A comes before B.

I've tried JSSort plugin but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Sort imports by modules** enabled in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Imports**, imports are sorted alphabetically by the module names when you run **Code | Optimize Imports**. Make sure that **Optimize Imports** is enabled in **File > Reformat File...**, or use **Optimize Imports** command for sorting